# Create a generic post/put/get in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typesafe

So I'm trying to learn writing more generic. I have POST/PUT/DELETE/GET for attatchments together with these entity types (there are also alot more entity types that I will need to add in the future).

This code works, and it is indeed more generic than writing 4 different getAttatchment with hardcorded personnel/workoder etc where it is ${apiType} currently. Some progress made atleast.

But how could I rewrite this even better? I would like to have e.g `getAttatchments<T>(EntityType<T> .....)` but I don't know how I could write it like that. And ofcourse it need to be typesafe so you don't actually pass entities that does not exist.

```
export enum EntityType {
  Personnel = 'personnel',
  Workorder = 'workorder',
  Asset = 'asset',
  AssetBooking = 'assetbooking',
}

  async getAttachments(id: string | number, apiType: EntityType) {
    return await this.get<AttachmentDetails[]>(
      `attachment/${apiType}/${id}/attachment`
    )
  }
```

Comment: is `AttachmentDetails` specific to one of the EntityType values?  or is that return type the same for all? Mayb you can elaborate on what you mean by `getAttatchments<T>(EntityType<T> .....)`

Comment: No it's the same for everyone. 
Only difference is how they're routed on the backend:

attachment/personnel
attachment/asset
attachment/workorder
attachment/assetbooking


etc.

What I mean is I want to skip enum EntityType and somehow make it generic with using T.

Comment: And then do _what_ with `T`? What is an example of when your approach fails to do something you need? If there is no example, then you don't need to make this more complicated by making it a generic function.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://catchts.com/api) article helps

Answer (score 1):

What you have already looks fairly generic but I would forgo the enum and use a union type instead. e.g.

```
type EntityType = 'personnel'|'workorder'|'asset'|'assetbooking'

type AttachmentDetails= any // whatever
// mock implementation
function get<T>( url:string) {
  return ''
}

  function getAttachments<T extends EntityType>(id: string | number, apiType: T) {
    return get<AttachmentDetails[]>(      `attachment/${apiType}/${id}/attachment`    )
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAogOxAS3AFUrAvDA5NAJwGcB7BBKAG1wB9cB3EggayYBMoDbcBDIoqCG58BIAEYkSzZAgDmuYKEwwAgiBA8AxgAsAtlCQARQT2SUiOHgjAwA9LZj1tPEFABunRQDMArgk0oZDCyggA8aAB8ABQwPgSUAFxEIAQysgCUMADewDAwBIJxCHgKAL6Keb7%20gcUhIGoaOvpIROEwUAAerghsRPBIqGAY0NHIbAkwyalyMDQwCD66YpwANDA8EMjDUBNomTl5eQUgRcFhDVp6BiDGGmZEANoAutGHhwAGLo1XSLYAJFkNltMKV-lkxqCvpdmiB3m90rkYKUgA)